# Smart-phone app developing

Tags: android, iphone

I am new to smartphone-apps. I have a site where users can get messages and alerts. Now I would like to make an app so that the user can be alerted(with a ringtone maybe?) that he/she has got a new message on the site.
My app will be made for Android and iOS(hopefully). My questions are: is it worth making such an app? If yes, is everything free for Android, or do I have to pay something? How about iOS: what do I have to buy in order to be able to create an iPhone app?

Comment: pls tell what you had tried so far, what problem you had faced, we are here for helping the people who had tried something and got struck in somewhere, sure this question should be down-voted, so edit this question in such way that what u have tried and what is your problem? Read the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq of Stack Overflow

Comment: @SankarGanesh I know it will be down-voted, but I simply do not know where to start from. I don't know what legal issues there are etc. I do not own a smart-phone, and I do not know anybody who could provide an advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum to get started publishing apps is pretty much;

- Android: A computer, an Android device for testing and [a one time $25 fee](https://market.android.com/publish/signup)
- iPhone: A Mac, an iPhone for testing and [$99 per year](http://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enrollment.html)

Comment: iPhone: $99 **per year**

Comment: Thank you! Can I develop an iPhone app on Windows by simulating somehow the needed environment? Also, can I test the app on a Phone without having an account on apple or android?

Comment: @SarwarErfan Good point, updated answer.

Comment: So I have to pay those fees even if the app is for personal use only (a project)?

Comment: @Dragos Android, yes. iphone, well, yes... recommended, no. Google is your friend, I've never tried those hacks so can't recommend anything.

Comment: @Dragos Android you only have to pay to distribute, iPhone you have to pay to even test on the phone.

Comment: Thank you! Sadly, I can accept your answer only once.